# is it possible to pass route value using Ajax form submit?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, routes, form-submit

The question: how to pass route value to the controller along with the form using Ajax?

I normally submit form using Ajax like this

```
        function AjaxFormSubmit(frm) {
            var form = `#${frm}`;
            $(form).submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
                var actionUrl = $(form).attr('action');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: actionUrl,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    data: $(form).serialize(), 
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data); 
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

Usage :

```
        <button onclick="AjaxFormSubmit('formName')" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
```

The form itself

```
   <form id="formName" asp-action="Create" asp-route-id="somedata">
    .... some fields
```

Then I get the form submitted successfully but I never get the route value `asp-route-id`

I recive it in the C# controller side like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(TheModel modelName, [FromQuery]string id)
    {
        ......
        return Json(id);
    }
```

or ...   `[FromRoute]string id`

none of them is working

I get an empty white page with the value null !!

finally, how to pass route value to the controller along with the form using Ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if we want to use form to submit data to our server, we write your code like this, but not integrate ajax, in my code snippet, I added 2 buttons, one is using form data submit, another used ajax to send data:

[image]

```
    @model TestFormModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post" id="formName" asp-action="CreateAction" asp-route-id="somedata">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="prop1" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="prop1" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="prop2" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="prop2" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
         <button onclick="AjaxFormSubmit('formName')" class="btn btn-primary">CreateByAjax</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function AjaxFormSubmit(frm) {
        var form = `#${frm}`;
        console.log($(form).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://localhost:44385/home/CreateAction",
            data: {
                prop1:$("#prop1").val(),
                prop2:$("#prop2").val(),
                id:"somedata"
            }, 
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data); 
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

adding console log and we can see that there's no `id` property in the form.